# org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException:

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing

**Error**

```
Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[file [C:\Users\satish_pahuja\Desktop\BO_Office_Acc_Ext.txt]], input=[BOOfficeAccExt,B0001,00006746464646,S0001,BA0001,A,ABC,XYZ,UID,SatishPahuja,SatishPahuja,090909,151512]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:183)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:83)
    at gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch.FileBatchReader.read(FileBatchReader.java:38)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch.BatchProcessExtract.main(BatchProcessExtract.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.getBean(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:230)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:185)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180)
    ... 30 more

Sep 15, 2015 3:04:54 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=batchExtracts]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Exit Status : FAILED
Done
```

**job-report.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:orcl="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl/spring-data-orcl-1.0.xsd">

    <batch:job id="batchExtracts">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="csvFileItemWriter"
                    processor="csvFileItemProcessor" commit-interval="20" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch.FileBatchReader">
    </bean>

    <bean id="csvFileItemProcessor" class="gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch.FileBatchProcessor">
    </bean>

    <bean id="csvFileItemWriter" class="gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch.FileBatchWriter">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in database -->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory -->

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**FileBatchReader.java**

```
package gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class FileBatchReader<BoOfficeAccExtract> implements ItemReader {

    public BoOfficeAccExtract read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
    ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        System.out.println("Inside read method-0-");
        FlatFileItemReader<BoOfficeAccExtract>  reader =new FlatFileItemReader<BoOfficeAccExtract>();
        Resource res=new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\satish_pahuja\\Desktop\\BO_Office_Acc_Ext.txt");
        reader.setResource(res);
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract>(){{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(){{
                setNames(new String[] {"extFileName","boId","officeAccountNo","solId" ,"bankId","ind","freeField1","freeField2","freeField3","modifiedBy","createdBy","modifiedDate","createdDate"});
            }});

            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract>() {{
                setPrototypeBeanName("BoOfficeAccExtract");
            }});
        }});


        reader.open(new ExecutionContext());

        BoOfficeAccExtract boOfficAccExtract=reader.read();

        return boOfficAccExtract;
    }
}

**BO_Office_Acc_Ext.txt**
BOOfficeAccExt,B0001,00006746464646,S0001,BA0001,A,ABC,XYZ,UID,SatishPahuja,SatishPahuja,090909,151512
```

**Main class**

```
package gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class BatchProcessExtract {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.egd", "file:///dev/urandom");

        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   "com/mgnregs/res/database.xml", 
                "com/mgnregs/res/context.xml",
                "com/mgnregs/res/job-report.xml" 
            };

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("batchExtracts");

        try {

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

I am getting this error and tried many things like removing space between values in txt file , adding double inverted commas with all the values. Please help me on this

```
package gov.in.dop.rsi.mgnregs.batch;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class FileBatchReader<BoOfficeAccExtract> implements ItemReader {

    public BoOfficeAccExtract read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
    ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        System.out.println("Inside read method-0-");

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"extFileName","boId","officeAccountNo","solId" ,"bankId","ind","freeField1","freeField2","freeField3","modifiedBy","createdBy","modifiedDate","createdDate"});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract>();
        fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("BoOfficeAccExtract");

        DefaultLineMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract>();

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        FlatFileItemReader<BoOfficeAccExtract> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<BoOfficeAccExtract>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\satish_pahuja\\Desktop\\BO_Office_Acc_Ext.txt"));
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);


        reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        BoOfficeAccExtract boOfficAccExtract=reader.read();

        return boOfficAccExtract;
    }
}
```

Comment: BoOfficeAccExtract is a simple POJO class

Comment: Please, describe what your code is expected to do

Comment: There is no bean named `BoOfficeAccExtract` and your config / reader is borked... Why on earth are you wrapping a reder with a reader, reopening it on each call? Wy not just put it in the configuration?

Comment: I have to implement the code using spring batches which will read the information from txt file which will be having comma separated value and to write into the database. But I am getting the error while reading only.

Comment: No you don't... I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Batch documentation how it works and what it does. Your code is the problem, the code is written because you don't understand how the framework works. I really hope your processor and writer aren't the same because that will lead to issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters drop that ugly reader you have, you are reading the same line over and over to each call to `read()`. Just use configuration not a reader wrapping a reader.

This is also because the `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` requires a `BeanFactory` (it implements `BeanFactoryAware` but due to your setup that never gets called.

Basically drop your reader and simply configure it in XML. Replace your `cvsFileItemReader` bean definition with the following (*fix the packages as I haven't included those*).

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="C:\\Users\\satish_pahuja\\Desktop\\BO_Office_Acc_Ext.txt" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="extFileName,boId,officeAccountNo,solId,bankId,ind,freeField1,freeField2,freeField3,modifiedBy,createdBy,modifiedDate,createdDate" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="BoOfficeAccExtract" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or you could use Java based configuration instead of XML.

```
@Configuration
public class CsvJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader cvsFileItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\satish_pahuja\\Desktop\\BO_Office_Acc_Ext.txt"));
        reader.setLineMapper(csvLineMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract> csvLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(csvLineTokenizer());
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(csvFieldSetMapper());
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineTokenizer csvLineTokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"extFileName","boId","officeAccountNo","solId" ,"bankId","ind","freeField1","freeField2","freeField3","modifiedBy","createdBy","modifiedDate","createdDate"});
        return lineTokenizer;
    }

    @Bean
    public FieldSetMapper csvFieldSetMapper() {
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BoOfficeAccExtract>();
        fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("BoOfficeAccExtract");
        return fieldSetMapper;
    }


}
```

Comment: What will be the solution if I want to use customReader class not the xml based configuration.

Comment: @Deinum Please find above updated Reader class and still not working. As in the future I have to read csv file from FTP server and how it would be possible if I will go to xml based configuration only.

Comment: Xml or java config doesn't matter. Your reader is flawed it won't work. If you want FTP, I would strongly suggest combining Spring Integration with Spring Batch (for either file polling on the local system or remote polling) which would make it completely transparant. Basically where the resource comes from doesn't matter.